# Using querySelectorAll on data- attribute javascript (no jQuery)

Tags: javascript

I know how to select for specific classes using querySelectorAll .  But How would I select for DOM object with specific data- attributes.

For example:

```
 <div class="person">
    <div class="detail" data-field="name">Tim</div>
    <div class="detail" data-field="age">24</div>
    <div class="detail" data-field="hair">black</div>
</div>
<div class="person">
    <div class="detail" data-field="name">Tim</div>
    <div class="detail" data-field="age">34</div>
    <div class="detail" data-field="name">red</div>
</div>
<div class="person">
    <div class="detail" data-field="name">David</div>
    <div class="detail" data-field="age">56</div>
    <div class="detail" data-field="name">brown</div>
</div>
```

If I want to select DOMs  with a specific class e.g 'detail'

```
 document.querySelectorAll('.detail')
```

My question is, How would I select for all doms with 'data-field = name?'

Answer (score 6):

Use [Attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)

> [attr=value]
>
> > Represents an element with an attribute name of attr and whose value is exactly "value".

```
document.querySelectorAll('.detail[data-field="name"]')
```

Answer (score 4):

You want to use the attribute selector

```js
// every element with a data-field attribute
var dataFieldElements = document.querySelectorAll('[data-field]');
console.log(dataFieldElements);

// only those elements that have their data-field attribute equal to name
var dataFieldNameElements = document.querySelectorAll('[data-field=name]');
console.log(dataFieldNameElements);
```

```html
<div class="person">
    <div class="detail" data-field="name">Tim</div>
    <div class="detail" data-field="age">24</div>
    <div class="detail" data-field="hair">black</div>
</div>
<div class="person">
    <div class="detail" data-field="name">Tim</div>
    <div class="detail" data-field="age">34</div>
    <div class="detail" data-field="name">red</div>
</div>
<div class="person">
    <div class="detail" data-field="name">David</div>
    <div class="detail" data-field="age">56</div>
    <div class="detail" data-field="name">brown</div>
</div>
```